# How to check input parameter for running shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a shell script to be used for various purposes. Various operations depend on input parameters. How can I check which parameter has been passed to the shell script while it runs?

Can someone please explain how this query will work? Say I've 1 shell script `abc.sh` which takes 1 input parameter and depending on its value the shell script should or should not do something. Say I've passed '1' as an input parameter and scheduled a run. While the shell script runs, how do I test the parameter's value?

Comment: Parameters are stored in `$1`, `$2`, …  Just have them tested (haha!) with the usual tools (`[ … ]`).  Maybe you want to edit your question to be a bit more specific otherwise. ;)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried reading a shell scripting tutorials? They are plentiful - randomly picking from the first search page: http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osCmdLineScriptStruct.php

Comment: Do you want to "test" the parameter values from _inside_ the running script or from _outside_, e.g. from another shell/another process?

Answer (score 3):

```
_fn() { set -- "$@" $(cat)
    while ${1+:} false ; do 
        echo "$1" && [ "$1" = "arg2" ] && echo "$1"
        $YOUR_CHK
        shift
    done
}

echo "arg2" | _fn "arg1"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
arg1
arg2
arg2
```

That handles both cmd-line args and `stdin`. It only runs the `while` loop to check them while you still have at least one argument saved in your parameter array. It does discard every argument it checks, so part of `$YOUR_CHK` should be saving information you think valuable in one way or another.

`_fn` would behave the same if its contents were the body of a script, or as is in the form of a shell function.

`_fn` handles `stdin` - in this case `"arg2" echo`ed over the `|pipe` - in the first line by `set`ting its positional parameter shell `$@`array to everything passed on the command-line - or `"$@"` - AND everything `cat` spits out via `$(command substitution)`.

`while _fn's $1` first parameter is `${set+}` we substitute the shell's built-in `:true` to satisfy the `while` loop conditional. As soon as `$1` is unset that substitution fails to happen, the conditional evaluates to `false` and the `while` loop breaks.

For every iteration of the `while` loop the `_fn() echo`es its `$1` first parameter `&&` if successful (`echo` is *always* successful) `[ tests ]` to see if `$1` equals the string `"arg2"` `&&` if the `[ test ]` is successful `_fn() echo`es `$1` again.

`$YOUR_CHK` is a null-op - it is an unset variable that evaluates to nothing before ever the shell executes any code.

For every iteration of the `while` loop we `shift` away the `$1` first parameter. So on iteration 1 `"$@"` looks like:

```
arg1 arg2
```

But after we `shift` the first time it looks like:

```
arg2
```

And after we `shift` the last time it looks like:

So this brings us back around again to `${1+:} false` - because `$1` is now unset the shell will not substitute `:true` and instead only `false` is evaluated, which breaks the `while` loop and ends the `_fn().`

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for reply. but didn't get you. Can you please explain how this query will work. Let me explain my requirement. Say I have 1 shell script abc.sh which take the 1 input parameter and on the basis of parameter shell script will do something. lets say I have passed '1' as input parameter and scheduled for run. shell script is running and I want to check what parameter i have passed to shell script.